# How can I split a string (with no spaces) into separate strings?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to read in multiple strings that belong to a vector of structs from one line, but the string has no spaces.
Here is basically my problem:

File data:

> G01G02G03G04G05

And when I read it in:

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    File>>vector.at(i).string
```

And what I get is the first string in the vector as

> G01G02G03G04G05

Where I would rather have it:

> vector(1)=G01;
>   vector(2)=G02... and so on

Sorry forgot some information, Im in C++ vs2010 and it is always three characters long, starting with either G,R,C,D

Comment: which langauge do you use? if it is always 'G' in front, use it as separator and prepend to every read value

Comment: sorry, its in c++ and not always G, it could be only be either G, R, C, D

Comment: Are the tokens always three characters long, though?

Comment: Yes it is always three characters long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would split the substrings into a vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> parseData(const std::string& s)
{
    if (s.size() % 3 != 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("incorrect data length");
    }

    std::vector<std::string> result;`enter code here`
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= s.size() - 3; i += 3) {
        result.emplace_back(s, i, 3);
    }

    return result;
}
```

See [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6490a84cd988e58) for a full compilable demo.

You could [generalise](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cae473d50daa12c) this to support any length sub-strings.

Answer (score 1):

C++ cannot know that you want it chopped up like that; you could equally want each character in a separate string. of in bunches of 2 characters,....

Read it into one string then chop the string up

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
     std::string bit = instr.substr(i * 3,3);
     vec.push_back(bit);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"Yes it is always three characters long"*

Then it could look the following way:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens;

std::string line;
if (getline(cin, line)) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); i += 3) {
        tokens.push_back(line.substr(i, 3));
    }
}
```